# How can I include the results of reading parts of a txt into a dataframe in python?

Tags: python, list, dataframe, printing, text-files

I am working with a long txt file, of which I have the structure, and need the positions on the code below (form every line) in a list, so I can put them into a data frame and work with them:

```
with open('File.txt','r') as file:
lines = file.readlines()
for line in lines:
    a,b = 0,2
    c,d= 2,19
    e,f= 44,52
    g,h= 52,64
 print(line[a:b],line[c:d],line[e:f],line[g:h])
```

The results come out right in the print() above, but I cannot seem to put it into a list with the following code:

```
list([line[a:b],line[c:d],line[e:f],line[g:h]])
```

The result of the prior code is just a list with all the correct positions but only of the very last line on my data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
a, b = 0, 2
c, d = 2, 19
e, f = 44, 52
g, h = 52, 64

##### Read the text file
with open(r"File.txt","r") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()    

##### Convert the text data to Dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame([[line[a:b], line[c:d], line[e:f], line[g:h]] for line in lines])
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the print statement..

```
list((line[a:b],line[c:d],line[e:f],line[g:h]))
```

or

```
[line[a:b],line[c:d],line[e:f],line[g:h]]
```

for your comment:

```
with open('File.txt', 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    your_list = []
    a, b = 0, 2
    c, d = 2, 19
    e, f = 44, 52
    g, h = 52, 64

    for line in lines:
        your_list.append([line[a:b], line[c:d], line[e:f], line[g:h]])
```

Comment: Hi! thanks so much for the response. I did just that and it only returns the last line of my whole txt file